# whichever of you/whoever of you

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, singular-vs-plural

a. Whichever student hands in their homework by the end of the week will get a prize.

b. Whichever student**s** hand in their homework by the end of the week will get a prize.

c. Whichever of you hands in their homework by the end of the week will get a prize.

d. Whichever **one** of you hands in their homework by the end of the week will get a prize.

e. Whichever **ones** of you hand in their homework by the end of the week will get a prize.

f. Whoever of you hands in their homework by the end of the week will get a prize.

Which could be used instead of

Those students/those of you who hand in their homework by the end of the week will get a prize.

In other words which have or could have a ***plural meaning***?

Answer (score 2):

A. and d. obviously mean 'one student', which doesn't make sense unless you change it to *Whichever student hands in their homework* **first**.  C. and f. imply 'one' because of the singular verb 'hands'.

That leaves b. and e. as definitely referring to more than one student.